# How can I get my Melampodium "Million Gold" to flower?

Tags: flowers, ground-cover

I have tried growing [*Melampodium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melampodium) var. Million Gold on my balcony. It grows on a coir sheet with soil spread on it. It only keeps spreading and growing leaves but no flowers.

What conditions does it need to flower?

Comment: Hi zestzeal! It looks like you have a couple of user accounts. I've asked the site administration to merge them, which will allow you to [edit](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) on your question). Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said how deep the soil layer is, but really, if you want it to grow sufficiently to produce flowers, put it in a pot with drainage holes, in free draining potting medium - you need some depth of soil (6 inches minimum) for the plant to mature sufficiently to get to the flowering stage.

Comment: The starting plant starts in a pot. The extensions are on coir